# GridBagLayout with vertical scrollbar

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

I try to make a chart using a `GridBagLayout`, which I admit is pretty difficult, mainly because it doesn't seem to be the best way for that purpose...

Now I try to have a vertical scrollbar so I can basically have as many rows as I want into this `GridBagLayout`, but I can't find a way to do it. I tried the most straightforward (and maybe naive) way, but it doesn't look to work:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TestCode2_Scrollbar {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame window = new JFrame("Test");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(400, 200);
    window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 150));

    JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());      
    window.add(panelMain);

    //Comment the next 2 lines when using without scroll bar
    JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane();
    panelMain.add(scrollPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    GridBagLayout innerLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints innerConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();     
    JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(innerLayout);
    innerPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 220, 250));

    //Comment one of the 2 following lines:
    scrollPanel.add(innerPanel);        
    //panelMain.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    innerConstraints.weightx = 0.0;
    innerConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
    innerConstraints.gridy = 0;

    innerConstraints.gridx = 0;
    JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Title / ");
    innerLayout.setConstraints(lblTitle, innerConstraints);
    innerPanel.add(lblTitle);               

    innerConstraints.gridx = 1;
    JLabel lblRating = new JLabel("Rating / ");
    innerLayout.setConstraints(lblRating, innerConstraints);
    innerPanel.add(lblRating);

    innerConstraints.gridx = 2;
    JLabel lblCategoryCode = new JLabel("Category code / ");
    innerLayout.setConstraints(lblCategoryCode, innerConstraints);
    innerPanel.add(lblCategoryCode);

    innerConstraints.gridx = 3;
    innerConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
    innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description");
    innerLayout.setConstraints(lblDescription, innerConstraints);
    innerPanel.add(lblDescription);

    int max = 4;

    for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {

        innerConstraints.weightx = 0.0;
        innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        innerConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        innerConstraints.gridy = i + 1;

        innerConstraints.gridx = 0;
        lblTitle = new JLabel("" + i);
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblTitle, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblTitle);           

        innerConstraints.gridx = 1;
        lblRating = new JLabel("" + i);
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblRating, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblRating);

        innerConstraints.gridx = 2;
        lblCategoryCode = new JLabel("" + i);
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblCategoryCode, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblCategoryCode);

        innerConstraints.gridx = 3;
        innerConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        lblDescription = new JLabel("" + i);
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblDescription, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblDescription);

    }

    innerConstraints.gridy = max + 1;

    JPanel innerVoidPanel = new JPanel();
    innerVoidPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 250, 250));
    innerConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
    innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
    innerLayout.setConstraints(innerVoidPanel, innerConstraints);
    innerPanel.add(innerVoidPanel);

    //...

    scrollPanel.add(innerPanel);        
    window.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work", and provide an SSCCE so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: The scrollable area is defined by one of two properties. For a component like JPanel, it is the panels preferred size, however, y override this by using a Scrollable interface

Comment: Provide sscce  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions

Comment: Had you tried, first adding the components to the `innerPanel`, then adding this `innerPanel` to the `JScrollPane`? Not like the sequence you described in your question, rather upside down...!!!

Comment: @nIcE cOw Yes just tried, no effect, which doesn't surprise me.

Comment: @JB Nizet, Sanyam Goel Well yes you're right, I usually do but thought it won't be necessary here. Obviously it is :)

Comment: @MateiFocseneanu : [The code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5b4orwm4wlq0p76/GridScrollerExample.java) written by me, is working fluently at my side, as said in the answer below, the sequence in which you adding components is not right :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove all the lines where you add the innerPanel to the scrollpane. And instead, add these two lines at the end of the main method:

```
JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
panelMain.add(scrollPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Complete code:

```
public class TestCode2_Scrollbar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame window = new JFrame("Test");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(400, 200);
        window.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(350, 150));

        JPanel panelMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        window.add(panelMain);

        //Comment the next 2 lines when using without scroll bar

        GridBagLayout innerLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints innerConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        JPanel innerPanel = new JPanel(innerLayout);
        innerPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 220, 250));

        //Comment one of the 2 following lines:
        //panelMain.add(innerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        innerConstraints.weightx = 0.0;
        innerConstraints.weighty = 0.0;
        innerConstraints.gridy = 0;

        innerConstraints.gridx = 0;
        JLabel lblTitle = new JLabel("Title / ");
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblTitle, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblTitle);

        innerConstraints.gridx = 1;
        JLabel lblRating = new JLabel("Rating / ");
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblRating, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblRating);

        innerConstraints.gridx = 2;
        JLabel lblCategoryCode = new JLabel("Category code / ");
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblCategoryCode, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblCategoryCode);

        innerConstraints.gridx = 3;
        innerConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
        innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        JLabel lblDescription = new JLabel("Description");
        innerLayout.setConstraints(lblDescription, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(lblDescription);

        int max = 4;

        for(int i = 0; i < max; i++) {

            innerConstraints.weightx = 0.0;
            innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            innerConstraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
            innerConstraints.gridy = i + 1;

            innerConstraints.gridx = 0;
            lblTitle = new JLabel("" + i);
            innerLayout.setConstraints(lblTitle, innerConstraints);
            innerPanel.add(lblTitle);

            innerConstraints.gridx = 1;
            lblRating = new JLabel("" + i);
            innerLayout.setConstraints(lblRating, innerConstraints);
            innerPanel.add(lblRating);

            innerConstraints.gridx = 2;
            lblCategoryCode = new JLabel("" + i);
            innerLayout.setConstraints(lblCategoryCode, innerConstraints);
            innerPanel.add(lblCategoryCode);

            innerConstraints.gridx = 3;
            innerConstraints.weightx = 1.0;
            innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            lblDescription = new JLabel("" + i);
            innerLayout.setConstraints(lblDescription, innerConstraints);
            innerPanel.add(lblDescription);

        }

        innerConstraints.gridy = max + 1;

        JPanel innerVoidPanel = new JPanel();
        innerVoidPanel.setBackground(new Color(0, 250, 250));
        innerConstraints.weighty = 1.0;
        innerConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.VERTICAL;
        innerLayout.setConstraints(innerVoidPanel, innerConstraints);
        innerPanel.add(innerVoidPanel);

        //...

        JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);
        panelMain.add(scrollPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanx, you put you finger on something sensitive, which is the constructor of `JScrollPane`. The only decisive thing is to write `JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(innerPanel);` instead of having these two lines: `JScrollPane scrollPanel = new JScrollPane(); scrollPanel.add(innerPanel);`. I must admit I don't really understand the reasons of this behaviour, but now it work so that's the main thing.

Answer (score 0):

Code looks good to me. If you want to see the scroller always, try to set the scrollbarpolicy for scrollpane as below.

```
scrollPanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
scrollPanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

This should help

Comment: No effect, sorry, not really the point. But anyway thanx for trying to help me.

Comment: Try to execute the provided code (just added the whole thing). You will see nothing but a grey rectangle, no matter if I add your code or not (except for the scroll bars).

Comment: I assume that was your problem that you cant get the scroll bars. Right? If you not getting the data then you must have done something wrong with adding sequence.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be related to any sequence (which is normal from my point of view). See accepted answer, it's a bit weird but well, that's the point.